# MYSQL check to see if a query generates values any of which appear in a given List

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a string field in `Table A`. It comprises a list of comma separated values stored in a field labelled X:
eg. "a,b,c,d,e,f"

I have `Table B` which has a field Y which may have any permutation of these values 
eg "a", "a,c", "b,c,d"
or even totally different values:
eg "m,n", "g,i,l"

I need to select all the rows in `Table B` using a MYSQL query where field Y has at least one letter which appears in field X in `Table A`.

Can anyone help me out with what the query may look like?

I've tried something like the following with little joy even playing around with groups - my SQL is quite poor hence the difficulty in making sense of how to go about a query like this:

```
SELECT y FROM B WHERE y IN (SELECT x FROM A);
```

Comment: You could try using `FIND_IN_SET()`

Comment: Fields should not contain comma-separated values.  Use the proper data structure for storing lists.  It is called a table.

Comment: To enlarge on @GordonLinoff's comment - your tables don't fulfill requirements of the first normal form, and it's considered reasonable for your schema to be compliant with the third normal form. These normalization conditions were laid out by Ted Codd, the creator of the relational model.

Comment: each value in table 1 should be in a separate row. That will save you a lot of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - the problem is that it is open source code where I'm using a plugin to do a query - I don't have control of redesigning the tables or restructuring them.

Comment: The problem with FIND_IN_SET() is that it will search for a string in a comma separated list - I need something a little different. I need effectively a search of a comma separated list to see if any one of them appears in a different list (or results from a select).

Comment: Open source? So change it ! Or don't use an RDBMS

Comment: The standard way to change it is through plugins - changing the core means it no longer will work with upgrades etc - that's why the core is not open to change.